# GitLab API - How to GET the repository/project files and metadata?

Tags: python, json, git, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am new to GitLab and using API calls and am confused on how to make a call to get the repository/project files and metadata. My current API call is as follows:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects?private_token=privateToken
```

privateToken at the end of the line above is replaced with my private token which I have taken out for obvious security reasons.

This will return to me the json that describes all of the projects I have, but I want to drill down deeper and see the specific information about the files that are stored within each project/repository. On the GitLab API documentation website, it lists this:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path
```

However, since I am new to GitLab and API calls in general I am confused as to how to edit my first link to retrieve this information.

Ideally, I would like to be able to drill down to the project/repository files and metadata within python and not have to edit the first link above, but I am not sure if that is possible. How does GitLab return the json? As a hash table of hash tables, if so, how do I navigate through it?

Any clarification on how to parse through the json and drilling deeper within it would be greatly appreciated!

I am using Python 3.6.1.

Comment: Answer: After further testing I figured it out. After making a generic API call, you can take the ID of any project from the first call, put it after the '/projects' and then route to any information that you want. Was unable to figure out the ':file_path', but was able to get other API calls working.  https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/id(id number from gitlab )/repository/tree?private_token=privateToken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've partly answered your own question in the comment (you can post that as an answer).

As for the `:file_path`, take a look at the [API for repo files](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repository_files.html).

> ```
> GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path
> ```

CURLing:

> ```
> curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK' \
> 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=master'
> ```

You haven't given a `file_path` you want to use, so taking gitlab-ce as an example - the file [`"app/models/key.rb"`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/models/key.rb), is url-encoded to `app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb`:

```
curl --request GET \
'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=master'
```

The [`project id`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project) can be specified as the integer `id` or the [URL-encoded path](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding). So instead of `13083`, the project namespace `gitlab-org/gitlab-ce` url-encoded can be used as:

```
curl --request GET \
'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/gitlab-org%2Fgitlab-ce/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=master'
```

You may also want to look at using an existing API like [pyapi-gitlab](https://github.com/pyapi-gitlab/pyapi-gitlab).

Answer (score 9):

Python solution
Very useful information about gitlab api.

[python-gitlab.readthedocs.io](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable)

```
import gitlab
# private token or personal token authentication
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.company.be', private_token='dklsfjksldjfkdsjf', api_version=4)
gl.auth()

project = gl.projects.get('path/to/project')
items = project.repository_tree()

print(items)
```